# How do I create a table with in Sql whose records are all permutations of columns in other tables (question body will clarify)

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Say I have tbl_nums:

```
num

1

2
```

And tbl_letters:

```
letter

a

b
```

How can I create a tbl_combo whose records are the permutations of these two tables:

```
number letter

1           a

2           a

1           b

2           b
```

Comment: This is called a Cartesian product

Answer (score 2):

use [cross join](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/cross-join.php#:~:text=The%20SQL%20CROSS%20JOIN%20produces,functions%20like%20an%20INNER%20JOIN.).

```
select 
    num,
    letter
from tbl_nums
cross join tbl_letters
```

output:

```
| num | letter |
| --- | ------ |
| 1   | a      |
| 2   | a      |
| 1   | b      |
| 2   | b      |
```

Answer (score 2):

Just adding this in addition to the answer already given by @zealous.  In MySQL, an inner join with no `ON` condition is actually allowed, and in fact defaults to being a cross join.  So, in MySQL we could also use:

```
SELECT n.num, l.letter
FROM tbl_nums n
INNER JOIN tbl_letters l;
```

Answer (score 1):

you may try this to create a table from the output of the query:

```
select a.num, b.letter into tbl_combo from tbl_num a, tbl_letters b
```